# Telerik MVC Extension Grid: How to get filterBy JavaScript to work?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, telerik, telerik-grid, telerik-mvc

Tried to research this the best I could, but couldn't find a basic example.  I have an ASP MVC 3 project with a Telerik Grid. Some of the columns of the grid are hidden because of space constraints.  There is a separate UI element that should allow the user to select filter values for all the columns, visible or hidden.  I know there must be a way to control the filtered contents of the grid from outside the View on the Client side - [this telerik help page](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-mvc/telerik-ui-components-grid-client-api-and-events.html) states:

> filterBy:
>
> Returns the current filter expression of the grid. The initial value is "" (empty string). Check the filter JavaScript method for additional reference.

But I can't find the additional reference.  From what I can glean from the web I should do something like this:

```
var grid = $("#Grid").data("tGrid");

grid.filter("OrderID~eq~10248");
```

But when it tries to execute I get the following JavaScript error:

> grid.filterBy is not a function

What am I doing wrong?  And can someone point me  to the details of the filterBy method?

**EDIT:**

I changed my code to:

```
$("#btnFilter").click(function (e) {
    var grid = $("#Grid").data("tGrid");
    grid.filter("Off_Plan~eq~'No Funds'");
});
```

Still get the same kind of error:
    grid.filter is not a function

Obviously I am newbie at telerik. Seems like I am missing some telerik javascript files...?  I started this Visual Studio project as a new Telerik MVC Application. The script registrar is there and I've added 
    
to the _Layout.cshtml.  Groan...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you're mixing up two things.

There is a **property** on the grid called `filterBy` which gets the actual filter.
And there is a **method** on the grid called [`filter`](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-mvc/telerik-ui-components-grid-client-api-and-events.html#filter) which filters the grid based on with the given filter expression.

Here is some code:

```
var grid = $("#Grid").data("tGrid");

var currentFilter = grid.filterBy; //it will be ""

grid.filter("OrderID~eq~10248"); // filtering the grid with OrderID equals 10248

currentFilter = grid.filterBy // now it will return "OrderID~eq~10248"
```

So that's why `grid.filterBy("OrderID~eq~10248");` as a method is not working.

EDIT:

The client side filtering is only working if you've enabled filtering for the grid (see also in doc under [Important notice](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-mvc/telerik-ui-components-grid-client-api-and-events.html#filter))

```
@(Html.Telerik().Grid(Model)
    .Name("Grid")
    .Filterable())
```

Comment: I tried your solution; see my edit to the original post.  Still failing with the same comment...grid.filter is not a function

Comment: I was able to repro your issue when the grid was not filterable. See my updated answer. If it doesn't solve your problem please post your grid building code.

Comment: One last question: do you know of a resource from which I can get a list of the operators that work in filter()?  I know about 'eq', and I think I have seen a 'startswith' and maybe a 'substring'...dying to find documentation on this.

Comment: I think the [telerik documentation of filter](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-mvc/telerik-ui-components-grid-client-api-and-events.html#filter) lists all the available `filterOperator` and `filterFunction`.